# JQuery multi select check box dropdown is not unchecked on browser refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JQuery multiselect checkbox dropdown.

```
$("select").multiselect();
```

i have two divs in the same html page. in both the divs i have multi select checkbox dropdown.
on browser refresh, the values checked are not unchecked.To solve the issue, i kept below the code.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
$("select").multiselect("uncheckAll");
};
```

But the problem is above code unchecks the values of multiselect checkbox only in one DIV. in other DIV's multiselect check box the values are not unchecked. How can i solve the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: even though you perform uncheck all operation after browser refresh all values in select will be reset to its original value (may be selected in your case)

Answer (score 0):

Try using proper selectors for the select boxes ie) give seperate ids and perform you function of checking or unchecking.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("select").each(function(){
    $(this).multiselect("uncheckAll");
});
```